# Building a dynamic game board based on the number of players

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

my friends are trying to learn JS (plus some CSS and HTML) and the project we chose to work on was building a board game. The boardgame we are trying to build is traditionally a 4 player game (thus a square board), however, by turning the square board into a circle we can scale the board to accommodate *n* players. The game is simple with players going around the board completing events (think monopoly).

The current plan is to scale the board for the number of players that are playing simultaneously. A 4 player game has *52* squares so a board for *n* players should have *13n* squares.

By taking a look at some boardgame implementations, we found that the most common framework was to either import an image of the board or build a CSS grid and translate the position of game pieces based on that. The problem with both is that they are not dynamic. Hard coding multiple boards and then displaying a specific one is not something we want to do.

[Rough image of board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmvn5.png)

What would be the best practice to implement the board?

Comment: You could create a canvas, draw a circle on it, and then subdivide that circle for the number of players...

Comment: Working on it gimme 10 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a canvas, draw a circle on it, and then subdivide that circle for the number of players...

```js
const gameboardHeight = 300,
  gameboardWidth = 300;
var numPlayers = 4; // Change for amount of players
const canvas = $('#gameboard')[0]; // Get the canvas
const context = canvas.getContext('2d'); // Get the canvas 'context' to draw on
const slider = $('#players')[0];
slider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  numPlayers = parseInt(e.target.value);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  renderGameBoard(context, gameboardHeight, gameboardWidth)
})
renderGameBoard(context, gameboardHeight, gameboardWidth);

// Render the game board
function renderGameBoard(ctx, bh, bw) {
  // Center-based coordinates
  function coordsFromCenter(pos, h, w) {
    var centerX = w / 2;
    var centerY = h / 2;
    return vec2(pos.x + centerX, pos.y + centerY);
  }

  // Draw angled line
  function lineAtAngle(pos1, a, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos1.x, pos1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(pos1.x + r * Math.cos(Math.PI * a / 180.0), pos1.y + r * Math.sin(Math.PI * a / 180.0));
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  // Get the center of the canvas
  let center = coordsFromCenter(vec2(0, 0), bh, bw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  //center x, center y, radius, start angle, end angle (radians)
  ctx.arc(center.x, center.y, Math.min(bh, bw) / 2 - 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();

  let numSubdivisions = numPlayers * 13;
  let degreesBetweenSubdivisions = 360 / numSubdivisions;
  for (let line = 0; line < numSubdivisions; line++) {
    lineAtAngle(coordsFromCenter(vec2(0, 0), bh, bw), degreesBetweenSubdivisions * (line + 1), Math.min(bh, bw) / 2 - 10);
  }
}

// 2-Axis vector for keeping track of positions
function vec2(x, y) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameboard" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="players" value="4" min="1" max="10" step="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so helpful. Would you recommend any other JS resources to use?

Comment: I can definitely recommend the Fireship youtube channel to everyone...